# jQuery: Multiple selectors including this

Tags: jquery

i want to select ´this´ and something else. for example:

```
$(this + ', ' + this + ' > div')
```

how can i make this work? Is this possible in a single selector?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`.andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) to hop back in the chain and include the element before as well, like this:

```
$(this).children("div").andSelf()
```

So we go from `this` to it's children, then [`.andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) adds to that collection what was in the chain before, which was `this`.

Comment: very nice thank you. I assume there is no way to do this in one selector string?

Comment: @meo - nope, since `this` is an object.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a result to another:

```
$(this).add('div', this)
```

Comment: Note that this would add *all* descendant `<div>` elements, not just children.